# error message : objectReferencePoint is only support for mode 1

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am currently learning corona game development, but for the following code :

```
local background=display.newImage("bacground.png")
local city1=display.newImage("4.jpg")
city1:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
city1.x=0
city1.y=960
```

give me the following error message :

> objectReferencePoint is only support for mode 1

but why?

Answer (score 0):

The new way to set reference points is through "anchor points". You can read up on it here:

https://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/10/15/tutorial-anchor-points-in-graphics-2-0/

Or, you can switch your graphics mode to 1.0.

Comment: While the link you provide may very well give an answer to the question, it would be helpful if you also provide a short summary of what can be found there. Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to create a good answer.